# Touchpad does not work in Lenovo 4152

Tags: 10.10, touchpad

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 in lenovo 4152...After the installtion the touch pad doesnot work...I am not able to find any drivers for this. Can anyone please suggest how to get the driver working..thanks

Comment: We need more hardware information - See this question for what commands to run: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

`sudo echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe`

Then, reboot.

*From [here](http://caseytinsley.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/ubuntu-10-10-touchpad-fix/)*